# how can i solve position sticky not working

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I built this section in shopify its a type of header like section. I need this to be sticky while scrolling but position sticky is not working

```
{%- assign brandLogo = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0614/2741/7328/files/Eternel_Hemp_Flag_Only.png?v=1644764193 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0614/2741/7328/files/3.png?v=1644656245 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0614/2741/7328/files/2.png?v=1644656283 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0614/2741/7328/files/1.png?v=1644656326'| split: ' | '-%}

<div class="main-brands" style="pointer-events:all;position: sticky!important;  top: 0;  position: -webkit-sticky;height:40px;">
  <div class="brands-inner" >
    
    {% for link in linklists.brands.links %}
        <a class="brand-item {% if link.active%}active{% endif %}" href="{{ link.url }}"><img src="{{- brandLogo[forloop.index0] -}}" alt="" class="brand-logo"></a>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="annoucement-bar">  <span class="sitewide-oyuy8v"><a href="#move" class="sitewide-54h87n-pc">  SUBSCRIBE & SAVE 10% </a> PLUS FREE SHIPPING ON YOUR FIRST ORDER</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="mob-annoucement-bar">  <span class="sitewide-oyuy8v"><a href="#move" class="sitewide-54h87n">  SUBSCRIBE & SAVE 10% </a> PLUS FREE SHIPPING ON YOUR FIRST ORDER</span> </div>
<style>
  .annoucement-bar{
    margin-left:200px;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-top:12px;
    color: white;
  }
  .sitewide-hnuaw{
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
  .sitewide-54h87n-pc{
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  }
  .sitewide-54h87n{
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  }
  .sitewide-54h87n-pc:hover {color:white;}
  .sitewide-54h87n:hover {color:white;}
  .main-brands{background-color:black;}

.brands-inner {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
}
.brand-item {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  padding:5px 5px;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -ms-flex-pack:center;
  justify-content:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  -ms-flex-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:40px;
}
.brand-item.active {
  border:1px solid #759B90;
   background-color:#759B90;
}
.brand-item:hover {
  background-color:#759B90;
}
.brand-item img {
  max-width:50px;
}
  @media (max-width:767px) {
    .brands-inner {
      -webkit-box-pack:center;
      -ms-flex-pack:center;
       justify-content:center;
      -webkit-box-align:center;
      -ms-flex-align:center;
       align-items:center; 

}
  }
    @media (max-width:767px) {
    .annoucement-bar {
      display:none;
}
  }
    @media (min-width:767px) {
    .mob-annoucement-bar {
      display:none;
}
  }
  .mob-annoucement-bar{
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 5px;
  }
  a {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more text, so you can scroll. It's working.

```
position: sticky;
```

This is enough.
http://jsfiddle.net/jcatoy3x/